# implementing vectorized backpropagation not converging

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, mnist

I am really new to machine learning and have taken up to week 5 in Andrew Ng's courser course on machine learning, where we apply backpropagation on the mnist data set. But I wanted to try to implement a vectorized version from scratch in python.

I have tried for a really long time and just don't truly understand why the cost that I get out converges incredibly slowly and stays at a very high rate. (ie, 1st step: 137336.70 2nd step: 137203.66).

I can't get the cost down to a reasonable rate and I think I am not implementing the backprogation algorithm correctly when I update my weights and biases. I am a little confused with the dimensions and also the functions I am using, I am trying to use a SoftMax function for the output layer, and tanh for the hidden layers. the output is a matrix of (m, 10), since it is one-hot-encoded.

I looked at this video for reference when implementing a vectorized implementation https://youtu.be/7bLEWDZng_M

```
m = len(y_train)
w1 = np.random.rand(784,25)
b1 = np.ones((59999))
w2 = np.random.rand(25,10)
b2 = np.ones((59999))

#X is a (59999, 784) matrix
# is a (59999, 10) matrix
# W1 is (25,784)
#W2 is (10,25)


alpha = 0.1
for i in range(2000):
   #forward prop
   Z1 = W1.dot(X) + b1
   A1 = tan_h(Z1)
   Z2 = W2.dot(A1) + b2
   A2 = softmax(Z2)

   #back prop
   dz2 = A2 - Y
   dW2 = (1/m) * dz2.dot(A1.T)
   db2 = (1/m) * np.sum(dz2, axis=1, keepdims = True)
   dz1 = W2.T.dot(dz2) * tan_h_p(Z1)
   dW1 = (1/m) * dz1.dot(X.T)
   db1 = (1/m) * np.sum(dz1, axis=1, keepdims=True)

   W1 = W1 - alpha*dW1
   b1 = b1 - db1
   W2 = W2 - alpha*dW2
   b2 = b2 - db2

   if i % 250 == 0:
      print(calc_cost(Y,A2))
```

Please any help with this would be very appreciated, I am very novice but would really like to understand how to implement this in scratch.

Comment: Why do you not apply alpha for bias update?

Comment: I absolutely have no idea. I guess I forgot somehow. But I tried applying that fix, so thank you. But I still can't get it to work. It still is not converging..anything else you think might be wrong with my code please let me know. Thank you